# Is MGET atomic?

Tags: redis

If I fetch the value of multiple keys with MGET, is it guaranteed that nothing will be able to modify any of the keys requested while the command is being processed and until redis returns them? The [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/mget) unfortunately says nothing about the atomicity of this command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - MGET is atomic. All of Redis' commands are.

Comment: I've heard this before, but would appreciate some background info about it to confirm.

Comment: Redis is single threaded - once it starts processing an operation, it will continue processing it until it is finished and only then will it proceed to the next one.